# Is there a way to name all the elements of list

Tags: r

Is there a way to name all the elements of list using names in array `element_names`.

```
element_names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

x <- list()
for (iter in 1:5) {
  x[[iter]] <- seq(1, iter)
}
```

Comment: Where is array `element_array` in your code ? Do you mean vector `element_names` ? If you do then `names(x) <- element_names` will do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this more concise using `Map` and `setNames`.

```
x <- setNames(Map(seq, 1:5), element_names)
x
# $A
# [1] 1
# 
# $B
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $C
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $D
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# $E
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or, using the new pipe:

```
Map(seq, 1:5) |> setNames(element_names)
```

Comment: `lapply(1:5, seq_len)` is more idiomatic than `Map(seq, 1:5)` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to generate a seq of list in R:

```
element_names <- LETTERS[1:5]
# initialise a list
x <- list()

# Loop through the length of list
for (i in seq(1,5)){
  vals <- seq(1, i)
  x[[element_names[i]]] <- vals
}
```